# Regular points on an effective Cartier divisor is regular on the whole scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think this should be an easy question to answer but I'm being unable to prove it. Vakil, in one of his notes, states that

> Suppose $X$ is a finite type $k$-scheme (such as a variety), and $D$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $X$ (Definition 8.4.1), and $p \in X$. Show that if $p$ is a regular point of $D$ then $p$ is a regular point of $X$. (Hint: Krull’s Principal Ideal Theorem for tangent spaces, Exercise 12.1.B.)

Does anyone know how to prove this? And can anyone provide some intuition behind this?

Comment: Intuitively what should happen here is that since divisors are codimension 1 bits of the scheme, they should have tangent spaces that are 1 dimension less than the tangent space of the ambient scheme. Connect this with the fact that singular is equivalent to having a too-big tangent space and we see the result. I'll write up a real answer in a bit, but I wanted to make the intuition comment first.

Comment: The argument is that if I have two numbers $a\leq b$ and $a-1=b$ or $b-1$ then I must be in the latter case and hence $a=b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should translate this into algebra:

> Given a local noetherian ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ and $f \in \mathfrak m$ a non-zero divisor, such that
>   $R/(f)$ is regular. Then $R$ is regular.

To proof this (with the notation from @Hoot 's comment), let $a=\dim R$ and $b=\dim \mathfrak m /\mathfrak m^2$.

Then we have

- $a \leq b$, since this holds for any local ring.
- $a-1 = \dim R/(f)$ by Krull's prinicipal ideal theorem.
- By the assumption, we have $a-1 = \dim (\mathfrak m/(f)) /(\mathfrak m/(f))^2$

To conclude, note that $(\mathfrak m/(f)) /(\mathfrak m/(f))^2=\mathfrak m /(\mathfrak m^2 + (f))$ and this fits into an exact sequence $$0 \to (\mathfrak m^2 + (f))/\mathfrak m^2 \to  \mathfrak m /\mathfrak m^2 \to \mathfrak m /(\mathfrak m^2 + (f)) \to 0,$$

hence $a-1 = b- \dim (\mathfrak m^2 + (f))/\mathfrak m^2 \in \{b,b-1\}$.

Finally, we deduce the desired $a=b$. And a posteriori we get $a-1=b-1$, hence $\dim (\mathfrak m^2 + (f))/\mathfrak m^2=1$. This isn't surprising, since $f \notin \mathfrak m^2$ must hold for $R/(f)$ to be regular.

Furthermore, note that we have not assumed $R$ to be an integral domain, but a posteriori we deduce that $R$ is an integral domain.

---

More generally, if a point is regular on a complete intersection closed subscheme, then it is regular on the variety itself. The proof is of course obtained by just iterating the divisor case.

Comment: Technically the proof gets easier, when you dont work with $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$, but just with a minimal generating set of $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we ensure the equality in $$a−1=dim\, R/(f)$$?

Comment: If we divide out a non-zero divisor, the dimension drops by exactly one (if the ring is noetherian). Thats Krull's principal ideal theorem. Why don't you read about it?

Comment: Note that for the purpose of the proof, we only need that the dimension drop by at least one, i.e. $a-1 \geq \dim R/f$ is enough to finish the proof.

Comment: Note that this inequality is technically not really Krull' theorem but the fact that minimal prime ideals do not contain regular elements.

Comment: Oh I see. It makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MooS I don't think that's true. See 12.3.13 in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry (Feb 2024 version). In the ring $R = k[x]_{(x)}[t]$, there is a chain $0 \subsetneq (t) \subsetneq (x, t)$ and a maximal chain $0 \subsetneq (tx-1)$. Thus, $dim(R) = 2$ and $dim(R / (tx-1)) = 0$.